# Gatsby develop throws this error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:52179

Tags: build, gatsby

This error starts when I change the time zone of the Wordpress from where the data is pulled via gatsby-source-wordpress plugin. Before I changed the time zone everything was working fine.

The complete error:

```
C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\XXXX\XXX\2021\www\XXX-www\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:51116
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen (net.js:1503:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:8)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 51116
}
```

The development server is deployed, but right after that the app starts to update posts, create categories and other Wordpress data stuff:

```
info  gatsby-source-wordpress  update mediaItem getz-150lb (#425)⠀
⠀
info  gatsby-source-wordpress  create mediaItem tolva-getz-450lb (#445)⠀
⠀
info  gatsby-source-wordpress  create mediaItem bomba-transfer-co2 (#423)⠀
⠀
info  gatsby-source-wordpress  create tag getz (#417)
```

To finally crash throwing the mentioned error.

Gatsby info:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.5 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    npm: 7.5.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 90.0.4430.212
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.964.0), Chromium (90.0.818.66)
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^3.4.1 => 3.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-google-analytics: ^3.5.0 => 3.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^1.5.0 => 1.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^3.5.0 => 3.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^4.5.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^3.5.0 => 3.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^4.1.0 => 4.2.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^3.5.0 => 3.6.0
    gatsby-source-wordpress: ^5.5.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^3.5.0 => 3.6.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 3.5.0
```

Any ideas in how to fix this?
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-source-wordpress-experimental/issues/404) the issue is related more to Node dependencies rather than Gatsby.

Try lowering your Node version to `10`, remove your `node_modules` as well as your `package-lock.json`, and install the dependencies again as the thread suggests.

Comment: Yes I saw the GitHub that you mentioned. I will try to follow the recommendations, but it really annoy me that everything was working smooth and suddenly I have to downgrade and reinstall everything. I will report if this works. Thank you Ferran.

Comment: After one night and without any changes to the npm or libraries in the project, everything is working again. I am pretty sure that it had something involved with the time zone change in the Wordpress end. At least is working at this moment.

Comment: I'm glad you finally fixed the issue, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this release gatsby-source-wordpress@5.7.0-alpha-wordpress.0+fe81b6e978 .It will fix the issue, it worked for me  and suggested here on github [github issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30308)

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this page today when we were having the same issue... at first I completely skimmed over the "WordPress timezone" aspect, but then realized that we had just made the same change on our WordPress.

In my case, I had one post that I had published shortly before the timezone setting change, and that post currently exists with created/modified timestamps in the future. I set that post to "draft" and now gatsby develop is running.